# Why does Dapper fail when I add a table alias?

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, orm, db2, dapper

When I execute a query in Dapper without a table alias, it works with no issues, like so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ApplicationUsers
WHERE EmailAddress LIKE '%' || @EmailAddress || '%'
AND CreatedAt >= @CreatedStart
AND CreatedAt <= @CreatedEnd
ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC
LIMIT @Limit OFFSET @Offset
```

C#:

```cs
return await connection.QueryAsync<ApplicationUser>(sql, filter);
```

and the response is below:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "result": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Amjad",
        "lastName": "Aj",
        "name": "Amjad Aj",
        "role": "Admin",
        "emailAddress": "amjad@aj.com",
        "username": "amjad",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lastLogin": "2023-07-19",
        "created": "2023-07-19"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, when I add an alias to ApplicationUsers, `u`, it fails.

Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ApplicationUsers u
WHERE u.EmailAddress LIKE '%' || @EmailAddress || '%'
AND u.CreatedAt >= @CreatedStart
AND u.CreatedAt <= @CreatedEnd
ORDER BY u.CreatedAt DESC
LIMIT @Limit OFFSET @Offset
```

I get the response below:

```json
{
  "success": false,
  "result": {
    "message": "SQLite Error 1: 'no such column: u.EmailAddress'."
  }
}
```

I have tried using a table alias while connecting to databases other than `SQLite` such as `IBM Db2` and I still get a similar error:
`<column-name> is not valid in the context where it is used`.

What could have gone wrong when the table alias was added?

Comment: That error does not come from Dapper. Dapper is able to do what you ask. The fact that the error starts with *SQLite Error* is a hint, that it is SQLite that doesn't like your syntax.

Comment: But I would run the very same query in the DB Browser for SQLite and it would work .. fine. There is probably some sort of translation of the query that occurs in the middle layer (either Dapper or ADO.NET). I was wondering whether there were docs on table aliases that would help understand it further.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more reading, I just figured that by default Dapper maps columns to properties by name matching, and thus the introduced alias will prevent this native behavior to work properly. [More on it here](https://medium.com/dapper-net/handling-multiple-resultsets-4b108a8c5172).

Still appreciating more input on this question. Thanks in advance.